# Allow users to choose from multiple avatars while registration in drupal 7

Tags: 7

Currently I am working on a website registration page and I want a new user to select a default avatar from a given list if they have not uploaded a profile image while they are registering. I am using drupal 7 so avatar selection module is not compatible with this version so can you kindly suggest me some other way out

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Avatar Selection](http://drupal.org/project/avatar_selection) for custom images ?
Also you can try the [Gravatar](http://drupal.org/project/gravatar) module to use with this service.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module you can allow users to select images from a library or upload there own which sounds like what you want. I assume that functionality would apply to the user image, but I have not tried that. I know it works for image fields you create so you'll have to take a look, but either way seems like media module has the basis of what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion boombatower but what I needed is to allow users to choose an image from a default list of avatar that is displayed to them while they are registering in short something like the avatar selection module